# Failed to execute MS Graph backend request CreateGroupRequest - GroupCreationLimitExceeded

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to create group in MS Graph I get following error:

```
{  
   "errorCode":"GroupCreationLimitExceeded",
   "message":"Failed to execute MS Graph backend request CreateGroupRequest. The server failed to respond correctly. Response Code: Forbidden, Reason: Reason: Forbidden, Correlation headers: request-id: 9a1e183f-a04a-4e34-8549-50ce72f0df16\r\nclient-request-id: 9a1e183f-a04a-4e34-8549-50ce72f0df16\r\nx-ms-ags-diagnostic: {\"ServerInfo\":{\"DataCenter\":\"West US\",\"Slice\":\"SliceC\",\"Ring\":\"5\",\"ScaleUnit\":\"001\",\"Host\":\"AGSFE_IN_10\",\"ADSiteName\":\"WUS\"}}\r\nDuration: 140.1325\r\nDate: Fri, 17 Aug 2018 19:51:03 GMT\r\n"
}
```

Request URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups
```

Request body is:

```
{  
   "resourceBehaviorOptions":[  
      "WelcomeEmailDisabled",
      "SubscribeMembersToCalendarEventsDisabled",
      "HideGroupInOutlook"
   ],
   "resourceProvisioningOptions":[  
      "Team"
   ],
   "mailNickName":"Ievgengo_Team_0bbf8f48",
   "displayName":"Ievgengo_Team_0bbf8f48",
   "visibility":"Private",
   "mailEnabled":true,
   "securityEnabled":false,
   "classification":"HBI",
   "owners@odata.bind":[  
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/656a868f-b2ed-42da-a18b-10b3fe6817a9"
   ],
   "groupTypes":[  
      "Unified"
   ]
}
```

User doesn't have that many groups. Does somebody know why it is happening?

Comment: Can you provide us with the request URL and payload?

Comment: updated original post with the information

Comment: Agree, my bad I didn't go over it entirely, but now I did. So do you have an answer on my original question? Why do I get this error? Also, thanks for sharing the link with limitations, though which limitation are you referring to? I didn't find any related.

Comment: I am not sure if your issue caused by `"classification":"HBI"`, but you could remove it for a try. The link with limitation does not mention the limit of creating the group, but you could find the `classification` is read-only in my answer.

Comment: Also, I think my reply is helpful, even if it is not 100% correct, I could not understand why down-vote it, I have deleted it.;-(

Comment: I decided to down vote, because your reply was long, not relevant to my problem and link you sent me didn't contain any relevant information.

Comment: My understanding is that you have access to source code where this error is thrown - why it is so hard to just for error code I pasted and see where it is coming from?

Comment: Are you still encountering this issue?